# Need help in understanding linked list code in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, double-pointer

The following code I got from [linus on understanding pointers](http://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers).

```
typedef struct list_entry {
   int val;
   struct list_entry *next;
} list_entry;    


list_entry **pp = &head; /* pointer to a pointer */
list_entry *entry = head;

while (entry) {
    if (entry->val == to_remove)
        *pp = entry->next;            //6      

    pp = &entry->next;                //8   
    entry = entry->next;
}
```

Can anybody help understand line 6 and 8? If entry->val == to_remove, the line 6 is evaluated, and *pp becomes the next entry after removal, then what does line 8 do after that? The current entry has been removed, how can this entry be re-used in line 8?

In addition, I understand that *pp means the value of pointer pp, and &entry->next means the address of pp, I always feel confused about when * should be used, and when & should be used. Specifically, can line 6 be:

```
pp = &entry->next;
```

and line 8 be:

```
*pp= entry->next;
```

If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

The code from the blog is incomplete and assumes that only one element will get removed and that free is not necessary. If there are two or more consecutive elements to be removed the second one in the sequence will not get removed.

The correct code is, which also assumes that the nodes don't have to be freed:

```
while (entry) {
    if (entry->val == to_remove)
        *pp = entry->next;           
    else
        pp = &entry->next;  

    entry = entry->next;
}
```

And if you have to free the node:

```
while (entry) 
{
    if(entry->value == to_remove  )
    {
        *pp = entry->next;            
        free( entry ) ;
        entry = *pp ;
    }
    else
    {
        pp = &entry->next;               
        entry = entry->next;
    }
}
```

---

Writing the entire structure really helps understanding this.

```
struct Node
{
    int val ;
    struct Node* next ; //hint, this has an address too.

} ;
```

The trick is in the statement

```
pp = &entry->next ;
```

this looks like you are pointing to the `next` node, but in reality you are only taking the address of the pointer of the current node. *Big difference!*

So `pp = &entry->next ;` is almost equivalent to `prev = entry;` from the first example, the only difference is that you point to the address of the member `next` of the current  `struct Node` instead of pointing to the entire current `struct Node`.

Comment: Is &entry->next the address of the next node? Is it the same as "the address of the pointer of the current node"?

Comment: @ericyoung `&entry->next` is the address *of the pointer next* of the current node.

Comment: It is still not clear to me: if entry has been removed (and may get freed), why still the address of the pointer of the current node, &entry->next, can be used? For your reference, there is another different implementation: http://wordaligned.org/articles/two-star-programming

Comment: Node is not freed means node is still in the linked list?  Could you explain why *pp = entry->next; and pp = &entry->next; used as is in your node-not-freed solution, and not the other way? I always use them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In this sample code, pp stores the address of the 'next' member of the previous chain, so that in the case that the current chain is marked for removal, then the 'next' member of the preceding chain can be modified to point to the 'next' of the now to be removed chain. The indirect modification is done by means of applying the * operator.

Lines 6 and 8 ca not be modified as per your question because then the code would fail to achieve the desired effect.

1. Keep the address of the 'next' member of the previous (or head) chain.
2. Check if current chain is marked for removal.
3. if it is then use the pp reference to indirectly manipulate the previous chain's 'next' member to point to the 'next' of the current, so in effect the linked list will skip the current chain while maintaining its integrity.

Comment: Sorry I still did not get it on how the current chain will be skipped if lines 6 and 8 are modified. could you give more detailed explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What goes on here:

```
list_entry **pp = &head; /* pointer to a pointer */
list_entry *entry = head;

// we start with entry being head and pp being an address of head
while (entry) {
// while there is a list_entry which is not NULL...
    if (entry->val == to_remove)
        // if entry points to value that should be removed, 
        // then store the address of the next entry in whatever pp points to now
        // (which effectively means removing that entry)
        *pp = entry->next;            //6      
    // pp is now an address of the next entry
    pp = &entry->next;                //8   
    // move to the next entry to start the next iteration
    entry = entry->next;
}
```

What this code does: it goes over the list and eliminates all entries which are marked as removed.

How it does it:

- originally, `pp` points to the head.
- it goes over the list, starting from the head.
- whenever the value the current entry points to is marked as "removed", `pp` stores in the address of current list entry the address of the next list entry. If `pp` was pointing at head, that means that the head is discarded and it starts pointing to the next element. If `pp` was pointing at an element in the middle of the list, that means that this element is removed (because now previous element will point to the element after the one which is removed).
- after that is done, it moves the `entry` point to inspect the next value in the list.

Answer (score -1):

`&` means to return the address of something. `*` means to access the variable that the pointer points to.

So the lines:

```
pp = &entry->next;

*pp= entry->next;
```

Are different.

The first sets a pointer to contain the address of `entry->next`, while the second one sets the value of the variable pointed to by `pp` to be equal to `entry->next`.

The reason that `entry->next` can be referenced after it has been "removed", is because while it was removed from the linked list, it still exists in memory and can still be accessed.